# SE Leagues down

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Is displaying the panda of death

[image: Panda]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list page ([stackexchange.com/leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues)) was crashing when it tried to display Gadgets (which was removed last night).